# number of primes less than a number $N$ is $\tfrac{N}{\log(N)}$ ??

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, prime-numbers, definition, approximation

In my lecture notes it says that for $N \in \Bbb N$ there are $\tfrac{N}{\log(N)}$ primes which are less than $N$.

But say $N=20$, the primes less than $20$ are $1,2,3,5,7,11,13,17,19$, so there are 9 primes less than $20$. But $\tfrac{20}{\log(20)}=15.372$. Which is 1) a decimal number and 2) larger than 9 !

What's going on here, the statement in my notes must be written incorrectly right ?

Comment: It is either incorrect or you are misinterpreting it. The correct statement is that $\lim_{N \to \infty} \frac{\#\{\text{primes } \le N\}}{N/\log N} = 1$ or merely $\#\{\text{primes } \le N\} \ge c\frac{N}{\log N}$ for some $c > 0$.

Comment: (1) There are ony $8$ primes less than $20$, because $1$ is not a prime. (2) Also, $\frac{20}{\log20}\approx6.676$ assuming that your "log" with unspecified base is the natural logarithm. (3) See the previous comment.

Comment: yes, it should be natural logarithm (base $e$, not $10$) and see [this article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prime_number_theorem)

Comment: See https://primes.utm.edu/howmany.html for an overview. You should review the prime number theorem which states that number of primes not exceeding $N$ is asymptotic to $N/\log N$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your lectures notes are covering what is known as the prime number theorem.

Let $\pi(N)$ denote the number of primes $\leq N$. The prime number theorem states that

$$\pi(N) \sim \frac{N}{\log N} \  \text{as}  \ N \to +\infty$$

So, if you compare $\pi(20)$ with ${20}/{\log 20}$, you will find that $\pi(20)=8$ while ${20}/{\log 20}\approx 6.676$. But, what would happen if we increase $N$ to $100, 1000,$ or $10000$?

If you look at larger numbers of $N$,

\begin{array}{|c|}
\hline
N& \pi(N) & N/\log{N} \\ \hline
 1000& 168& 145&\\ \hline
 10000&  1229& 1086&\\ \hline
 100000&  9592& 8686&\\ \hline
1000000&  78498& 72382&\\ \hline
10000000&  664579& 620420&\\ \hline
10000000&  5761455& 5428681&\\ \hline
\end{array}

then you will see that $\pi(N)$ gets closer and closer to $\frac{N}{\log N}$ as $\ N \to +\infty$. This is why

$$\lim_{N\to\infty}\frac{\;\pi(N)\;}{\; \frac{N}{\log(N)}\;} = 1$$

The above relation also shows that $\pi(N)$ and $\frac{N}{\log N}$ are asymptotically equivalent which means that they will essentially become equal as $N$ becomes arbitrarily large.

Therefore, you should adjust your lecture notes to account for $\ N \to +\infty$ and then describe the relation hidden in $\pi(N) \sim \frac{N}{\log N}$.